# How to retrieve all the rows where primary key value found in the other column in the row in MySql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, php, hierarchy

Following is MySql Table in the snapshot: [image]

column sno could be found in the other rows in column p_sno. i.e.

```
sno = 5   linked through p_sno = 5 with sno = 6 (two rows)

sno = 8   linked through p_sno = 8 with sno = 9 while 
sno = 9  linked through p_sno = 9 with sno = 10 (three rows)
```

Similarly

```
sno = 13 linked to sno = 14 by p_sno = 13 (two rows)
```

Now, what i need from this table is to return

```
sno = 5 and sno = 6 if someone search by temp_no = 2017-05 or temp_no = 2017-06
```

Same thing with other rows for example if somebody search with temp_no = 2017-08 it should return three rows i.e. sno = 8, sno = 9 and sno = 10 and so on so forth.

help appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (easily) do one-level relations, and then `UNION` the results. That's what would take to get rows related to `temp_no = '2017-06'` (and with a query which is SQL standard):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
(
    -- Direct search
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        t AS t0
    WHERE
        t0.temp_no = '2017-06'

    UNION

    -- One level related
    SELECT
        t1.*
    FROM
        t AS t0
        JOIN t AS t1 ON t1.sno = t0.p_sno
    WHERE
        t0.temp_no = '2017-06'
) AS u
ORDER BY
    sno ;
```

Giving:

```
 sno | temp_no | first_party | second_party | p_sno
 --: | :------ | :---------- | :----------- | ----:
   5 | 2017-05 | Akhtar Ali  | Amir Khan    |  null
   6 | 2017-06 | Akhtar Ali  | Amir Khan    |     5
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=13dff7f4855e816914ab3b2f776529f4)*

NOTE: I've replaced your `p_sno = 0` values by nulls, which seems to me that better represents the meaning of this column.

---

You seem to want to find all descendants of a certain row, using a parent-child relationship between p_sno and sno. This is an indefinetly-deep multi-level hierarychy. If you use a database that supports recursive CTEs (such as MariaDB instead of MySQL) you can use the recursive CTE explained in: [Check CTE to get all children (descendants) of a parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914472/cte-to-get-all-children-descendants-of-a-parent).

If your question is restricted to MySQL, you can use the tecnique described by
[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query), that would make you produce the following query for your `temp_no = '2017-08'` use case:

```
 SELECT
     t_sorted.*
 FROM
     (SELECT 
         * 
     FROM 
         t
     ORDER BY
         p_sno, sno
     ) AS t_sorted,
     (SELECT
         @pv := 
         (SELECT
             sno
         FROM
             t
         WHERE
             temp_no = '2017-08'
         )
     ) AS init
 WHERE
     -- for first row
     t_sorted.sno = @pv  
     -- recursive query
     OR (find_in_set(p_sno, @pv) > 0 AND @pv := concat(@pv, ',', sno)) ;
```

```
 sno | temp_no | first_party | second_party | p_sno
 --: | :------ | :---------- | :----------- | ----:
   8 | 2017-08 | Amir Khan   | Saleem       |  null
   9 | 2017-09 | Amir Khan   | Saleem       |     8
  10 | 2017-10 | Amir Khan   | Saleem       |     9
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=691f46f789f90d3f21134bea2212c41d)*

Comment: your both solutions are good but deficiency in both are as: in first solution if i search with first occurence of the it does not show the next column while in the other solution is it the inverse to the first solution. the second one solution is good enough but let suppose i have 1,2,3,4 records connected througbh p_sno and i search with 3, it will show me only 3 and 4 not the 1 and 2...?

Comment: You can have a variation of the query without sorting, but efficiency will be bad. If you need to, you can have a UNION of the two versions (one sorted asc, the other sorted desc), or other setups. In any case, this method assumes that  *ancestors predate descendants*.